# Android Mobile Market : how to set the top left image

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I'm sorry if my english is bad, It's not my primary language.

I'm publishing my first app on the Android Market.

On the Web Market, everything is fine (dispite the lack of description, but i'm working on it).

I ve set up the feature image (1024*500). In my mind this image would be on the top left corner of the mobile market.
But no, I've uploaded the promotional image, (180*120) but it's always the same : a white box with my app icon in the middle.

How can I change this image ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's the 512x512 "High Resolution Application Icon" you can upload with your app. The 180x120 is used in the mobile app on the app details page or in the carousel if your app is featured, and the 1024x500 is shown on the Web market to the right of the high-res icon.

Comment: I think my explanation aren't clear.the image I 've talk about is the one in the detail of the app on the mobile market. (below the title, left of install button). I uploaded every pics possible in the page (feature, promo, hi res icon, screenshot) but the particular image is always like my icon, but small in the middle of the big white box

Comment: Ah, ok - as I mentioned above, the graphic used in the detail page on the mobile app should be the 180x120 "promo image." The changes you make might not take effect immediately (you may need to wait a few minutes and clear the market app's data on your phone), or may only take after you publish an update, but if it's still not working after that you may want to contact Market support (ha - well, unlikely to solve anything, but worth a shot).